# Will changing the name of a column in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio be reflected in stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have have been tasked with adjusting the names of columns in a database according to a naming convention in order to promote clarity and consistency.

The database in question has numerous stored procedures performing operations on the aforementioned tables. If I change the name of a column through the design option in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008, will this change automatically be reflected in the relevant stored procedures or will it require manually adjusting column names in all the sprocs to avoid corrupting the relationships?

Comment: **No.** You will have to go through each SP and update the columns. Best advice I could give is open up all the SP's and do a find replace in SSMS. I would be cautious with this method though.

Comment: Do it and tell us about your observations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Christian, my understanding is that you will have to make the changes in both places separately. So, change the column name and then change the name of the referenced column in all stored procedures from the old name to the new one.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. Please remove and update accordingly.